# Forward outgoing traffic for port to another server using iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I'm trying to forward outgoing traffic `194.97.114.3:2010` to another server but with no luck.

`netstat -anup` gives me

```
udp        0      0 94.23.28.183:44174      194.97.114.3:2010       ESTABLISHED 4218/ts3server
```

I have ip forwarding enabled and entered these two commands

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2010 -j DNAT --to-destination another_server:2010
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 2010 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

See if have enabled options:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

to enable this :

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```